# How to change background color for scatter plot in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, scatter-plot

How do I change the background color of a scatter plot in matplotlib?

Currently I have

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(X, Y, c=T, marker='o', s=(0.005*r), linewidth=0, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
plt.scatter(X_stars, Y_stars, marker='o', s=(0.00000005*r), color='white')

plt.savefig(filename, format='ps')
```

I want the background to be black, not white.
I already changed `facecolor` and `edgecolor` to black, but without the desired effect. Setting `transparent=True` made it transparent so that I could change the background in Photoshop, but it must work in matplotlib as I have a very large number of plots.

Comment: If you want to use the [state-machine interface](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#matplotlib-pylab-and-pyplot-how-are-they-related), you can add `plt.gca().set_axis_bgcolor('black')` after the calls to `plt.scatter`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

EDIT: As mentionned by endolith in the comments axisbg was deprecated in version 2.0 of matplotlib. Use facecolor instead.

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, facecolor='black')
```

You could use the axisbg argument of the add_subplot method. Here's a little example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = random(100)*10
b = range(100)
fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, axisbg='black')
ax.scatter(a,b)
fig.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: It's now called `facecolor`