# How to overlay precipitation data on a shapefile using matplotlib and pygrib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.4, shapefile

I have read this question- [Overlay shape file on matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728529/how-to-overlay-a-shapefile-in-matplotlib) and I am not sure it applies to me but I have a shapefile of my country and I want to overlay the precipitation data from a GRIB file onto that shapefile. This is using pygrib and matplotlib. I am not interested in using the Basemap.coastlines() and Basemap.countries() because that is available in the shapefile. I want to override that with my own shapefile. How do I do that ?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4
import numpy as np
import pygrib
import shapefile
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap


grbs = pygrib.open('00020000')

grb = grbs.select(name='Total Precipitation')[0]
data = grb.values
lat,lon = grb.latlons()
m=Basemap(projection='mill',lat_ts=10,llcrnrlon=lon.min(), \
urcrnrlon=lon.max(),llcrnrlat=lat.min(),urcrnrlat=lat.max(), \
resolution='c')
m.readshapefile("adm3.shp")
x,y=m(lon,lat)
cs = m.pcolormesh(x,y,data,shading='flat',cmap=plt.cm.jet)


m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,80.,5.),labels=[1,0,0,0])
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,180.,5.),labels=[0,0,0,1])
plt.colorbar(cs,orientation='vertical')
plt.title('Precipitation Plot')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand, because your code seems to basically work. I made a few changes:

- `resolution` kwarg in `Basemap` can be set to `None` because you won't use the built-in coastlines
- `m.readshapefile` requires a `name` argument

Using

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

grbs = pygrib.open('00020000.grb')
grb = grbs.select(name='Total Precipitation')[0]
data = grb.values
lat, lon = grb.latlons()

m = Basemap(projection='mill', lat_ts=10,
            llcrnrlon=lon.min(),
            urcrnrlon=lon.max(),
            llcrnrlat=lat.min(),
            urcrnrlat=lat.max(),
            resolution=None)

m.readshapefile("adm3", "countryname", color="red", linewidth=3)
x, y = m(lon,lat)
cs = m.pcolormesh(x,y,data,shading='flat',cmap=plt.cm.jet)

m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,80.,5.),labels=[1,0,0,0])
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,180.,5.),labels=[0,0,0,1])
plt.colorbar(cs,orientation='vertical')
plt.title('Precipitation Plot')
plt.show()
```

and some mocked data and country borders, I get a figure like the following:
[image: mocked precipitation map]