# how to change colors with cmap paired option in scatterplot?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, background-color, scatter-plot

I am trying to plot an array created by one hot encoding for nucleotide sequences. the sequences were positive and negatives and I wish to change the color of scatterplot with two different colors. Not sure what goes wrong here

```
dim1 = pca_result[:,0]
dim2 = pca_result[:,1]
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.scatter(dim1, dim2, cmap= 'YlGnBu' ,c=search_reg['NR+/-'], s=1)
plt.title("PCA for Negative data")
plt.xlabel('PCA 1')
plt.ylabel('PCA 2')
plt.show()
```

`dim1` and `dim 2`
 are arrays while the `search_reg['NR+/-']` contains values of 0s and 1s.
The graph plotted is in black and white but due to white background, its not clearly visible. 
How may I change the color of the graphs?

Comment: What are `dim1`, `dim2`, and `search_reg`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change background color for scatter plot in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989654/how-to-change-background-color-for-scatter-plot-in-matplotlib)